# Android NDK: unused import statement with header file

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I'm trying to add tracing to my C++ project in Android Studio, I'm quite simply following the example in the docs to create a small profiling library in my app: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/tracing

I get an 'Unused import statement' message on the "#include " line in Android Studio as well as `error: use of undeclared identifier 'ATrace_beginSection'` compile errors.  My CMakeLists.txt file for the library is:

```
project(profiling)

if(ANDROID)
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include)
    message(STATUS "Including ${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include")
endif()

set(profiling_SRCS
  profiling.cpp
  )

set(profiling_HEADERS
  profiling.h
  )

add_library(profiling STATIC ${profiling_SRCS} ${profiling_HEADERS})
```

I've checked the cmake log for the "message" entry above, ANDROID_SYSROOT is indeed pointing to the correct location.  The library shows up in the app->cpp section in Android Studio, the CMakeLists.txt file shows up in the External Build Files section, I've tried resyncing Gradle, I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, no dice.  My targetSdkVersion is set to 27 in my build.gradle.

What am I missing?

Comment: Other things I have tried that didn't work:

Comment: ** using the target_include_directories command, instead of include_directories. Neither of these changed $INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (I printed it with message before and after).  I also checked $INCLUDES in a grasp-at-straws moment

** using `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-I${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" )`.  This *did* update CFLAGS but the updated value still didn't make it into android_gradle_build.JSON .

(Sorry for the double-post, there's apparently a 5-minute-timeout on comment edits)

Comment: Gaaaah.  The problem was the minSdkVersion setting in build.gradle - trace.h has this at the top `#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 23`.  For whatever it's worth, I also don't  need to include ${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include in the CmakeLists.txt for this library...  Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Gaaaah. The problem was the minSdkVersion setting in build.gradle - trace.h has this at the top `#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 23`. For whatever it's worth, I also don't need to include `${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include` in the CmakeLists.txt for this library... Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your cmake file looks not complete. Try to add the path reference point using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. E.g.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project(profiling)

if(ANDROID)
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include)
    message(STATUS "Including ${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include")
endif()

set(profiling_SRCS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/profiling.cpp
  )

set(profiling_HEADERS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/profiling.h
  )

add_library(profiling STATIC ${profiling_SRCS} ${profiling_HEADERS})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion though.